# Cannot exit AWS CLI help pages

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

After installing `awscli`. I tried the help command as mentioned in the documentation,

```
$ aws help
```

When I do this, I can see the following page full screen. and can not seem to get out of it.

I tried `Ctrl+C` and it does not go back to my Ubuntu command line.

```
AWS()                                                                    AWS()



NAME
       aws -

DESCRIPTION
       The  AWS  Command  Line  Interface is a unified tool to manage your AWS
       services.

SYNOPSIS
          aws [options] <command> <subcommand> [parameters]

       Use aws command help for information on a  specific  command.  Use  aws
       help  topics  to view a list of available help topics. The synopsis for
       each command shows its parameters and their usage. Optional  parameters
       are shown in square brackets.
```

Comment: That is the man page. Press `h` to see available keyboard shortcuts/commands. `q` to quit

Answer (score 43):

The manual pages use the `more` command.

Some useful commands:

- <kbd>q</kbd>: quit
- <kbd>space</kbd>: next page
- arrows: scroll up/down -- your mouse will work, too
- <kbd>/</kbd>: search
- <kbd>h</kbd>: help

Reference: [Everything You Need To Know About The More Command](https://www.lifewire.com/what-to-know-more-command-4051953)

So, just hit <kbd>q</kbd>.

Answer (score 5):

Type Q, It will automatically exit

[image]

Comment: Please enter the image description above to the image link.

Answer (score 2):

Press q to exit.

You can find more detailed information here:
http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/more.1.html

Answer (score -1):

Adding "**&**" at the end suspends output/exits

aws ecr create-repository --repository-name backend **&**

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30940878)